# PHP - Correct way to add space between numbers?

Tags: php, numbers, space

Probably a simple problem if you know the answer.

**What I have**

Numbers with no spaces.

```
$str = 10000;
$str2 = 100000;
```

**What I want**

Convert above to below...

```
$str = '10 000';
$str2 = '100 000';
```

**Own thoughts**

I thought of some strpos, regexp, str_replace but is it really the way to solve this? I will accept the most correct, short code answer with no lack of speed.

Comment: where exactly you want space?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted o.O ?

Comment: Yes, its silly question, but one can optimize the code with better solution, so plz, its not always to Down-voted such question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [number_format](http://php.net/number_format) function. With `space` for thoudsandsSparator as below.

```
number_format($number, 0, '.', ' ')
```

[Codepad Demo.](http://codepad.org/Y0XCnRhC)

Answer (score 9):

Look no further than [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format).

Answer (score 4):

use [number_format](http://php.net/number_format):

```
$formatted = number_format(
    $number, $numberOfDecimals, $decimalSeperator, $thousandsSeperator);
```