# php if result column has number, add symbol $

Tags: php, numbers, addition, symbols

I use php to get information from stored procedures. From this, i get some column with numbers values and in the same column, sometime it's null or has others characters than numbers. I would like to add specific symbol "$" to the one with numbers only(positive or negative). This is what i've done until now :

```
    $sql = "financier_gl @DATE1 = '$from', @DATE2 = '$to', @TARGET = '001'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    //print_r( $row );  // debug code
    if ($row['HTML_CODE'] == 'BOLD(), Green()'){
        $couleur='green';
        $font= 'bold';
    }
    else {
        $couleur='black';
        $font= 'normal';
    } 
    if ($row['Montant'] > 0 ){
        echo '$';
    }
?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php echo "<tr style=\"font-weight:$font; color:$couleur;\">"; ?>
<td style="text-transform:lowercase"><?php echo ($row['Nom']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['Quantite']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['Montant']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['D/C']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['Debit']); ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['Credit']); ?></td>
```

As you can see, that's "Montant" column only that i would to ask $ and get value only. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean, that if `$row['Montant']` is a number, you want to `echo '$';`?

Comment: Usually it's a number, but the header has title text, and some others row of this column has NULL so doesnt show anything, i don't want to see "$" alone if there's not any numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if `$row['Montant']` is a number and then show a `$`, you could achieve this by doing something like this:

```
if (is_numeric($row['Montant'])) {
  echo '$';
}
```

Comment: @C.Jenkins Glad I could help.. Can you please accept it as the correct answer? :)

Comment: Done, in same time, there's any way to convert these number in 9 999.99 than 9999.99 ? just to create space between some number? thx

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677094/php-correct-way-to-add-space-between-numbers